# Remove unwanted Space and returns using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to remove Space and returns in between the elements only for the particular child element (i.e) for 'math' as mentioned below XML. I tried `<xsl:strip-space elements="m:math"/>`. But it removes space for all the elements. I am in need to retain the space after `<style>` element and space before `<b>` element.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <style>This is style</style> 
    <math display="block"> 
        <munder> 
            <mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi> 
        </munder> 
        <mo>=</mo> 
        <munder> 
            <mrow> 
                <munder> 
                    <mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi> 
                    <mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi> 
                </munder> 
            </mrow> 
            <mphantom>
                <mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi>
            </mphantom> 
        </munder> 
    </math>
    <b>This is bold</b>
</chapter>
```

XSLT tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><style>This is style</style> <math display="block"><munder><mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></munder><mo>=</mo><munder><mrow><munder><mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></munder></mrow><mphantom><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></mphantom></munder></math> <b>This is bold</b></chapter>
```

Comment: hey! my new answer, did it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to insert  `<xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>` wherever you want ..

Here I'm inserting this text `&#xA0;` (which introduces space) before copying every element that comes under node `chapter`..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//*[parent::node()[name() = 'chapter']]">
    <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"> <style>This is style</style> <math display="block"><munder><mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></munder><mo>=</mo><munder><mrow><munder><mi mathvariant="normal">BASE</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></munder></mrow><mphantom><mi mathvariant="normal">under</mi></mphantom></munder></math> <b>This is bold</b></chapter>
```

You can modify the condition to accommodate the additional space wherever you want..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I found that the code inserts space at places where there is no space in between elements. I just tested by inserting elements without space. But I got space. Please check

Comment: @siva2012, you mean.. your input XML has elements which have additional space infront of them .. and you want to retain that extra space?? XSLT doesn't work that way .. whitespace is whitespace, when you say no indentation and `strip-space`, it gets rid of all the whitespace in your XML. So that is the reason I inserted `&#xA0;` manually. Now that you have template to do that .. you can vary the conditions to **insert it yourself** ..

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer,, I'm inserting the space before element that is an immediate child of `chapter` element..

Comment: Thanks for your effort and your answers

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Though this answer isn't valid for this question I'm keeping it for reference since I have explained significance of each templates in `linearize XML` code.. And posting the relevant answer as new answer..

---

You don't need strip-space, this should do..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation:

```
<xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

indent = 'no' takes care of removing addition space between two nodes ..  `omit-xml-declaration` removes xml declaration from output XML. This is optional in your case..

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Copies nodes as is.. except without indentation ..

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Coverts unwanted whitespace characters to single-space char .. example:

```
<node>

    there is lots of     space
</node>
```

output will be like this:

```
<node>there is lots of space</node>
```

Comment: Space before <b> was removed when I use the code given by you. Please look into my Input XML. It contains space before the element `<b>`. Please check

Comment: @siva2012, I didn't see that .. I assumed you want to `Linearize the XML` .. And by the way, what's the reason for that additional space infront of just `<b>`?? Do you really need that?

Comment: Obviously, there is space before `<b>` element. This is used for pagination purpose. I really need to maintain the space before and after any element except inside `<math>` element using XSLT